# Compositing CIFilter with SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, blending, cifilter, skscene

Im trying to use a color dodge blend mode (CIFilter) on an image and composite it with my whole Scene (which is an SKScene node). CIColorDodgeBlendMode unfortunately does only take CIImage as an input for the Background. Is there possibly a workaround?

Basically i want the same result like in Photoshop having 2 layers and the upper layer has the color dodge blending mode applied.

Here is my code ('self' would be the SKScene node):

```
UIImage *inputUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inputImage.png"];
CIImage *inputCIImage = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:inputUIImage];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorDodgeBlendMode"];
[filter setValue:inputCIImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[filter setValue:self forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
SKTexture *outputTexture = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:cg];

SKSpriteNode * outputSprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithTexture:outputTexture];
[self addChild:outputSprite];
```